# Trying to make a html forum make an account and send an activation email

Tags: html, authentication, xhtml, login-script

I own a website and it is completely made out of html and other file extensions.
    But I got asked to make a ***login/signup***, I don't know how to make the login form store the data and send a confirmation email to the people before they can access their account?

Comment: you need to use server side technology like php, jsp, asp, etc

Comment: also a database would be nice, oracle or mysql are the most common

Comment: are you able to or have you used either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you will need to have some programming running on the server. If you don't want to learn to do that yourself, then there are a number of free systems available that will help you. Wordpress is a good example. You can add plugins to it to get it to work in the way that you need. You can find out more, and download it, at:
http://www.wordpress.org/

There is a directory of plugins at:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: Thanks I'll try that on my wordpress website but the one I am talking about is a ftp/file host website it is made with geocities.ws can you help!

Comment: Which package do you have with geocities.ws?

Comment: Well I suggest you find that out first, since I see their basic package does not include any server side scripting, which you will need in order to do what you want.

Comment: Well they do allow software running